# Как заменить придаточное причастным оборотом?

Tags: причастный-оборот

1) Гарнизонные солдаты по очереди подходили к Пугачёву, который принимал их в свою шайку.

Как правильно заменить придаточную часть этого сложноподчинённого предложения  обособленным определением, выраженным причастным оборотом?

1) Гарнизонные солдаты по очереди подходили к Пугачёву, принимавшему их в свою шайку.

2)Гарнизонные солдаты по очереди подходили к Пугачёву, принимающему их в свою шайку.

Спасибо.

Comment: Мне кажется, оба способа нежелательны, так как нарушают смысл (по меньшей мере, увеличивают вариативность). Не хватает в русском языке времен, поэтому их приходится расшифровывать придаточными предложениями.

Comment: А какого времени тут не хватает?

Comment: Плюсквамперфект тут был бы не лишним. *После того как солдаты подходили к Пугачёву, тот становился принимавшим их в шайку.*

Answer (score 5):

Ответ 1: Первый вариант правильный, т. к. глагол "принимал" прошедшего времени, от него образуется причастие тоже прошедшего времени "принимавший".  (Причастия обычно сохраняют время глаголов, от которых они образованы).

Ответ 2: Решила добавить здесь.

Если брать предложение изначально вне контекста, то вариативность последовательности действий появляется сразу. "Который принимал" - сейчас или раньше?

О времени причастий нашла следующее:   Полные причастия, являющиеся определениями, могут иметь **относительную форму времени**, которая определяется по отношению ко времени глагола-сказуемого.

Причастия настоящего времени выражают одновременность действий, обозначенных причастием и глаголом-сказуемым: Лодка, веслами махая, плыла по дремлющей реке (П.); Мальчик прислушивался к треску ломаемых медведем веток (Сераф.). В приведенных предложениях причастия имеют значение прошедшего времени, одновременное с действием глагола-сказуемого. В данном случае возможна замена причастий настоящего времени причастиями прошедшего времени без заметного изменения в значении.        Причастия прошедшего времени несовершенного и совершенного вида выражают действие, предшествовавшее действию, выраженному глаголом-сказуемым: - Экий бес девка! - закричал казак, расположившийся на соломе и мечтавший согреться остатками чая (Л.); Мы пошли на вал, возвышение, образованное природой и укрепленное частоколом (П.).   (http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-102.htm)

Получается, что для того, чтобы снять вариативность толкования и указать, что "принимал" Пугачев солдат в шайку в данный момент времени, а не раньше, нужно использовать причастие н.вр.  "принимающий".  Тогда правильным  (снимающим временную вариативность) будет предложение 2).

Comment: но если рассматривать по смыслу, то получается в первом варианте, что Пугачев принимал их раньше того времени, когда они подходили.

А в исходном придаточном действие проходило в тот момент, что и в главном.

По аналогии с предложениями: Он видел проплывающее бревно. и Он видел проплывавшее бревно.

Comment: Такие нюансы здесь не важны, это речь автора, который сам выбирает время. Кстати, подходили - тоже прош.вр., поэтому следует сохранить одно время, иначе будет грамматический недочёт - несогласованность во времени.

Answer (score 1):

Который принимал - принимавший; который принимает - принимающий. В нашем случае всё-таки прошедшее время.

Answer (score 1):

Действительные причастия настоящего времени образуются от основы глаголов времени с помощью суффиксов -ащ-, -ящ-, -ущ-, -ющ-.

Действительные причастия прошедшего времени образуются от основы глагола прошедшего времени с помощью суффиксов -вш-, -ш-.

У нас глагол прошедшего времени ПРИНИМАЛ, соответственно: ПРИНИМА- + -ВШ- + окончание = принимавшему.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то подумалось...
А ведь совершенно не очевидно, что причастия должны передавать абсолютное время (прошедшее, настоящее, будущее), а не относительное (до, во время, поле действия, выражаемого основным глаголом).

Сравните: 
Пугачев встречал солдат, принимая их в свою шайку. Не "приняв(ши)" же???

И для причастий:
Пугачев, принимавший их в шайку, встречал солдат.
Пугачев, принимающий их в шайку, встречал солдат.
Не уверен, что первый вариант правильнее второго, скорее наоборот.

Гарнизонные солдаты по очереди подходили к Пугачёву, сидевшему за столом.
Гарнизонные солдаты по очереди подходили к Пугачёву, сидящему за столом.

А тут?

Так почему же в исходной фразе так все однозначно (по мнению большинства ответивших)?
Не уверен...

Боюсь, что даже признав необходимость прошедшего времени (т.е. приняв сам ответ за правильный), мы должны пересмотреть аргументацию.
Такое ощущение, что тут глубже...
Прежде всего надо разобраться с грамматическим видом.
***Принимавшему*** - де-факто соответствует совершенному виду, по результату солдаты оказываются принятыми в шайку.
***Принимающему*** - соответствует несовершенному виду, Пугачев принимал, но не известно, принял ли.

В порядке бреда.

Comment: >А ведь совершенно не очевидно, что причастия должны передавать абсолютное время (прошедшее, настоящее, будущее)

А разве в русском есть причастия будущего времени? Не сочтите за придирку, самому интересно насколько нормативны образования вроде "умрущие".

Comment: Вообще-то есть. Считаются окказиональными.
Классический пример из Гумилева.

>Так вот что ожидает немцев, сейчас ***пойдущих*** в атаку, чтобы раздавить один-единственный несчастный эскадрон.    
  
Но я не совсем это имел в виду. Не грамматическую форму причастия (и иже с ним - деепричастия, отглагольного прилагательного, даже наречия), а именно отношения. Вот такая формулировка понятнее?

*А ведь совершенно не очевидно, что причастия должны передавать абсолютное время (прошедшее, настоящее, будущее - **как у глагола**), а относительное...*

Comment: Спасибо. +1 от меня.

Comment: Да не за что. Как вспоминаю сейчас, был такой некогда популярный форум на edu.ru, в самом начале двухтысячных, еще до Грамоты, кажется. Так там один вумный дядька (забыл, увы, и ник, и фамилию) мне эту идею насчет относительности времен именных форм глагола и продал. И что самое смешное, на пример из Гумилева он тоже указывал как раз в связи с этой относительностью. так что мы на пару, похоже, в чем-то его ход мыслей повторили.